# How to switch views in XCode's Storyboard via code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, input, uistoryboard

I'm wondering how you can switch views (ViewControllers, like a screen) using code. Here is my storyboard so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YyYY.jpg I'm trying to switch from the top left screen to the bottom left screen if the credentials the user entered are correct. Here's what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/aJMpNNzQ

I'm completely lost about how to switch views, I'm a beginner with XCode, I'm just trying to make a sample app, I like playing around. Also, if you know how to get the inputs from the text fields in the create account screen and put them in ViewController-m file please state that.

Thanks, Julian

Comment: Have you added your viewcontrollers to storyboard?

Comment: @Iphonenew Here's all I have for files, view2 is controlling the view in the top right (creating accounts section) http://imgur.com/Xv7AHjG

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to accomplish your goal. The simplest might be to create another "segue" from the top-left VC to the bottom-left VC, and name it.

Then somewhere in the VC, you make a call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfSegue sender:self];
```

Another way would be to programmatically instantiate the targetVC as follows:

```
UIViewController *targetVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someIdentifier"];

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:targetVC.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetVC animated:NO];
    }];
}
```

(note that my example also includes an animated transition that be changed to a number of apple supplied options)

The primary concept you want to wrap your head around in both cases is that you're "pushing" a new viewcontroller onto a "navigation stack" (an array of view controllers). lots of posts explaining difference between push and modal segues as well, and it's recommended you spend the time learning the difference.

Good luck on your learning!

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, I will try each step by step thank you so much, I'll let you know how it goes. :) @timothykc

Comment: Would I connect the segue from the vc to the other vc directly or do I use the login button as the origin? Also which type of segue should I use?

Comment: Either way. In storyboard, you connect a push segue, and using the property inspector give it a name. In the case of the login button, you make sure that you also create an IBAction that links to a method where performsegue is performed.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch to next by code also.. you have to give storyboardID to viewcontroller.

and push to that view by this code when you want to switch.

```
 UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 viewController *viewObj = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewObj animated:YES];
```

and it is also working without using `prepareForSegue` action.